# Check if folder exists based on a partial string, create new folder if it doesn't, change name if it does

Tags: powershell, scripting

Short version: I'm trying to get a looping if/else statement to work. What I'm trying to get it to do is check to see if a folder exists that contains a particular string ending in a three-digit number (the variable $FolderSeqSRC below); if it doesn't, I want to create a folder with that string as its name. If it does, I want it to increment up the three-digit number and then go through the process again. This is the code that I have:

```
$FolderDate = (Get-Date).ToString('yyMMdd');
$FolderSeqSRC = 1;
$FolderSeq = ([string]$FolderSeqSRC).PadLeft(3,'0');
$FolderDescript = "Test"

$NewFolderName = "$FolderDate-$FolderSeq $FolderDescript";
$FolderSearchName = "$FolderDate-$FolderSeq"
$OldFileName = "C0";
$NewFileName = "$FolderDate-$FolderSeq-";

Write-Host "$FolderDate";
Write-Host "$NewFolderName";

while (-not $completed) {
    if (-Not (Test-Path -Path $targetDir\$FolderSearchName*)) {
        "Path $FolderSearchName doesn't exist: creation in progress."
        $completed = $true     
    } else {
       "Path $FolderSearchName exists!"
        $FolderSeqSRC++;
        $FolderSeq = ([string]$FolderSeqSRC).PadLeft(3,'0');
        $FolderSearchName = "$FolderDate-$FolderSeq"
        $NewFolderName = "$FolderDate-$FolderSeq $FolderDescript";
        $NewFileName = "$FolderDate-$FolderSeq-";
        "Trying path $FolderSearchName next."
        $completed = $false
    }
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$targetDir\$NewFolderName"
    $completed = $true     
}
```

I'm halfway home. It checks successfully to see if a folder exists with a -001 in it, and if it doesn't, it creates it exactly the way I want. If the 001 folder does exist, it creates a -002 folder. The problem is it won't increment past -002. I thought I had it set up properly to loop, but apparently I'm missing something. An earlier attempt had it stuck in an endless loop that DID increment properly, so I know this is close.

(This is part of a larger script that retrieves files off a camera SD card so some of these variables may look extraneous but aren't.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so turns out as usual I was overthinking things. This is what finally made it happen:

```
$FolderDate = (Get-Date).ToString('yyMMdd');
$FolderSeqSRC = 1;
$FolderSeq = ([string]$FolderSeqSRC).PadLeft(3,'0');

$NewFolderName = "$FolderDate-$FolderSeq $FolderDescript";
$FolderSearchName = "$FolderDate-"

Write-Host "$FolderDate";
Write-Host "$NewFolderName";

$CheckPath = @(Get-ChildItem $targetDir -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name.StartsWith($FolderSearchName)}).Count;

Write-Host "Number of Existing Items: $CheckPath";

$FolderSeqSRC2 = $FolderSeqSRC + $CheckPath;
$FolderSeq = ([string]$FolderSeqSRC2).PadLeft(3,'0');

Write-Host "Increment should be: $FolderSeq"
PAUSE

$FolderSearchName = "$FolderDate-$FolderSeq"
$NewFolderName = "$FolderDate-$FolderSeq $FolderDescript";
$NewFileName = "$FolderDate-$FolderSeq-";
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$targetDir\$NewFolderName"
```

The answer was to simply not rely on an if/else loop--instead I found a way to tell Get-ChildItem to tell me how many folder names matched the partial string of the just the date, and then add that number to 1. The idea being that if it doesn't find any, then it adds 0, and the folder it creates is -001. If it finds two existing folders, it adds 2+1, to get me the new folder name 230106-003.

Comment: Some alternate methods of string formatting for a little less typing: `$FolderSeq = $FolderSeqSRC.ToString('d4')` or `$FolderSeq = '{0:d4}' -f $FolderSeqSRC`